# Customize Kendo grid column filter checkbox message

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to overwrite the message text in a grid column menu filter option. So instead of showing boolean value like "true/false", I want to show "Show X/Show without X". Here is my code,

```
columns.Bound(r => r.IsLinkable).TitleWithTooltip("Linkable").Filterable(f => f.Multi(true).Messages(m => m.IsTrue("Show X").IsFalse("Show without X")));
```

The **Messages** function is not working for **IsTrue()** and **IsFalse()** time. But the **Messages** function works for others like **CheckAll()** or **Cancel()**.

I am using Kendo 2015.3.930 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution,

```html
columns.Bound(r => r.IsLinkable).TitleWithTooltip("Linkable").Filterable(f => f.Messages(m => m.Info("Select item").IsTrue("Show X").IsFalse("Show without X")));
```